# ServerProtocolViolation error

Tags: c#, .net

I am hitting up a server with the following code and am encountering a ServerProtocolViolation error:

```
// Prepare the webpage
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url + queryString);

// execute the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Does anyone know how to work around this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the webserver that you're sending the request to isn't conforming to the HTTP standard.

Other than fixing the server or rewriting `HttpWebRequest` to be more generous, there isn't much you can do.

What URL are you requesting, and what's the text of the exception?

**EDIT**:  If you request the URL in [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), you'll see that the server didn't return any headers.  You should contact the owner of the server and complain.

As a workaround, if you run Fiddler while sending the request, Fiddler will fix the response and allow HttpWebResponse to parse it.

Comment: The URL I am requesting is: http://aviationknowledge.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/nph-findfrequency.cgi?Web=1&Space=ExpertPilot_v2&Frequency=.25&Words=lnav%0D%0Avertical%0D%0Avnav%0D%0A

The text of the exception is:
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note on another reason that I experienced:

If you configure your request to use a proxy server (i.e. through the [`HttpWebRequest.Proxy` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx)), and you use a wrong proxy port, there might also be a chance to see that error.

In my case, I configured `http://127.0.0.1/` as the proxy but had the actual proxy server running on `http://127.0.0.1:808/` instead (i.e. port "808" instead of "80").

If this is the case for you, try using no proxy or of course, configure the correct proxy port.