# Http Header request returns 'ServerProtocolViolation'

Tags: c#, http-headers, httprequest

I've got an interesting problem...
I'm messing around with a link checker program, here's the heart of it:

```
private static string CheckURL(string url)
{
    string status = string.Empty;
    string strProxyURL = "http://blah:1010";
    string strNetworkUserName = "blahblahblah";
    string strNetworkUserPassword = "blahblahblah";
    string strNetworkUserDomain = "blahblah";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(strProxyURL, false);
    proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strNetworkUserName, strNetworkUserPassword, strNetworkUserDomain);

    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.Proxy = proxy;

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        status = ex.Status.ToString();
    }

    return url + ";" + status;
}
```

... which I pinched from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55603/how-can-i-better-my-url-checker-program).

The problem is that for most URLs I feed it I get an 'OK' status.  But I have a page that acts as a PDF viewer that seems to return an OK when examined with Fiddler but shows 'ServerProtocolViolation' as the status within my checker.

I've noticed one oddity of the Fiddler result of this URL, it's got 3 instances of x-xss-protection and x-frame-options, but that's not going to stop it from working, is it???

Here's the Fiddler data:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: public
Content-Length: 230070
Content-Type: application/pdf
Expires: Tue, 27 Jan 2015 17:17:46 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
shortcut icon: href='http://www.jameshay.co.uk/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=JamesHayDocJHMP0016Doc2931.pdf
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Date: Tue, 27 Jan 2015 17:17:45 GMT
X-Cache: MISS from proxy-3_10
X-Cache: MISS from ClientSiteProxy
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ClientSiteProxy:3128
Connection: close
```

Edit (28/01 09:10am): 
When using Fiddler I replace the proxy with this...

WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);

The DocumentView page is the only one that still adds the x-xss-protection and x-frame-options via the code behind, as the web.config file has those settings too:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I presume it's that which is causing the duplication... but is a duplication really going to mess with the response?
(End of edit)

So what can I do to either get the http request to come back with an 'OK' within my code, or is there an alternative way of checking the URL exists that I can use?

Any help, as always, much appreciated :)

[Here's an example URL for the PDF viewer](http://www.jameshay.co.uk/DocumentView.aspx?DocumentID=2931&DocumentRef=JHMP0016)

Comment: Is Fiddler adding any of those duplicate headers to the response? Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066037/serverprotocolviolation-error this error will appear when the response consumed by the client (returned by the server) is not valid HTTP. Likely, you need to resolve something upstream, either at the server returning the PDF, or with your proxy, which in this case is Fiddler.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the original question - I think I have duplication of the settings both in the code behind and web config which explains the multiple occurrences.

Comment: I've got a test version of the site fixed so the DocumentView page only returns single instances of the security options... and still I get an 'OK' in Fiddler, but a 'ServerProtocolViolation' from my link checker.       Arghhhhh!